# Is there any templating engine for standalone application(SWT/Swing etc) just like Velocity etc

Tags: java, swing, swt, eclipse-plugin

As title says, is there any UI templating engine available for standalone applications (like SWT, Swing) just like we have apache velocity or freemaker available for web application?

Currently we are developing a product based out of eclipse, and I feel this UI is going to be customized/branded for some clients, so for each client we need to touch UI code. I did a research but didn't find any useful results.

We already developed a small prototype of engine which does basic UI controls templating, but before seriously digging into that project, I thought to consult experts here so that we don't re-invent wheel if there is already available. My idea is I should be able to change UI (at-least basic brandings like title bar text etc) so that we need not rebuild entire app for just tile bar change.

So I assume my question is clear, if required I can provide more details. Note: we were a pure Java EE shop and this is the first project we are doing on standalone side, sorry if I'm asking any obvious thing.

Comment: could you elaborate templating UI code? how does templating related to customizing/branding for some clients?

Comment: @sambireddy, one customer want few text boxes disabled and all title everything should be in his company name and another customer want few text boxes enabled with his company name.. an example scenario

Answer (score 0):

What about writing the UI code in a JVM based scripting language like [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/GUI+Programming+with+Groovy), JRuby